# simple solution for sizing sidebar of a react-admin app

Tags: react-admin

I simply want to define the width of the sidebar according to the documentation "Sidebar Customization" here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    sidebar: { // <- Error 'sidebar' does not exist in type 'ThemeOptions'
        width: 300, // The default value is 240
        closedWidth: 70, // The default value is 55
    },
});
const App = () => (
    <Admin theme={theme} dataProvider={simpleRestProvider('http://path.to.my.api')}>
        // ...
    </Admin>
);
```

I get a :

```
 'sidebar' does not exist in type 'ThemeOptions'
```

which is correct, when looking into `material-ui.core.styles.ThemeOptions`

What is the simpliest way to simply size the sidebar ? I like to do because my MenuItemLink texts overlaps the size of the sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createMuiTheme()` call is not needed:

```
const darkTheme = {
  sidebar: {
    width: 220, 
    closedWidth: 55, 
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped. Do you howto change the Appbar Color  the same way ? The Docu seems old, because 50% is not working there.

Comment: If you have the default AppBar color (color = 'secondary'), then:
const myTheme = { overrides: { MuiAppBar: { colorSecondary: { backgroundColor: '#EF476F' } } } }

Answer (score 0):

Only this code worked for me, because they don't export types on v3.9.4, but I am using TS.

```
import { ThemeOptions } from "@material-ui/core";

export interface CustomThemeOptions extends ThemeOptions {
  sidebar?: {
    width?: number;
    closedWidth?: number;
  };
}

const theme: CustomThemeOptions = {
  ...defaultTheme,
    sidebar: {
        width: 100,
        closedWidth: 40,
    },
};
```

issue https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5426

Comment: Now you can use what they say in the docs. The issue was fixed: `const theme = createMuiTheme({
  ...defaultTheme,
    sidebar: {
        width: 110,
        closedWidth: 40,
    },
});`

Answer (score 0):

With the current version `3.19.10` you also have to widen the menu if you don't want menu item labels to wrap at the original sidebar width of `240px`. e.g.

```js
import { defaultTheme } from "react-admin";

export const defaultAppTheme = {
  ...defaultTheme,
  sidebar: {
    width: 260,
    closedWidth: 55,
  },
  menu: {
    width: 260,
    closedWidth: 55,
  },
};
```

You can see where the menu widths are pulled from the theme and applied [here in their source code](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v3.19.10/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/layout/Menu.tsx#L15-L38)